# InDesign GREP: Italicized specific characters

Tags: adobe-indesign, italic, italics, grep-indesign

I want to use a GREP style to italicize a portion of a company name. For example: "In*Design*." Design is only italicized when it follows the word "In" but "Design" never appears italicized when it stands by itself.

Comment: And I want free pizza and a pony.

Comment: Maybe give us what you have tried to do this already? what has somewhat worked and what hasnt?

Answer (score 1):

Piece of cake. Use [Lookahead and Lookbehind codes](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/indesign/cs/using/WSFB3603CC-8D84-48d8-9F77-F3E0644CB0B6a.html#WS1952D538-1335-4b1d-BA5E-FA5A176FDC9Fa) to limit the match to "InDesign" only. Use word boundaries to make sure the entire word gets matched.

That leads to

```
(?<=\bIn)Design\b
```

where `(?<=\bIn)` is the **lookbehind** part: only "Design" should match when preceded by "In". The `\b` before and after indicate a **word break** -- there may not be an additional word character before or after the phrase. So it will match "In*Design*" but not "inDesign" (GREP is case sensitive by default), "wInDesign" (a word character before the `\b` word break), or "InDesigner" (a word character after the last `\b` word  break).